# Will I get an error if I log in to Microsoft account frequently?

Tags: authentication, error-handling, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

To use OneDrive API, I use [token flow authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/msa-oauth?view=odsp-graph-online#token-flow) to obtain an access token .

In general, I send a URL request using source code, then log in to Microsoft account and get an access token. Login is only requested for the first try since information are kept in browser cache .

However, when using RPA (Robotic Process Automation), the browser runs on a background process and the cache will not be kept. Therefore, it is necessary to log in to Microsoft account after sending the URL request every time. So far it seems to be ok but I am wondering that is it possible to get an error if I log in to Microsoft account too frequently in the long term?

Comment: 1) You are asking a question about a vendor's policy. Only someone at Microsoft directly involved in accessing quota and security information can answer. If that was my job, I would not answer your question. That answer will be valid for a very short time. Next month, the answer might be invalid. Microsoft security is very fluid and adapts. 2) You should be caching authorization tokens until they expire. It is bad practice to request tokens over and over before they have expired. You can be rate-limited. 3) Authorization is an expensive operation that can affect your performance.

Comment: I will keep your advice in mind. Thank a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my research it looks like this shouldn't be an issue unless you have certain security features enabled that check for this. I wouldn't worry unless you're attempting to sign in many times within a few seconds. In the case that you do get an error it should be easily fixable since we know where it's coming from.